# Spring login form switching from https to http

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

We have a Spring boot application with Spring security deploy on a server. We are using https but when the redirection is made to Spring default login form the redirection is call with http which cause a 503 Service Unavailable. I don't understand why Spring is switching the communication protocol, is there a way to prevent it?

our configuration

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/status", "/actuator").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

**page to redirect :**
[image]

[image]

**login :**
[image]

Comment: That still looks like a proxy problem. Are your sure that there is no other proxy? You shouldn't get 503 without a proxy AFAIR.

Comment: Just found out the solution there https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https. Thanks for pointing out the proxy @dur if you want to make an answer, I'll put it as the resolving awnser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution there https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https

It was a proxy problem, I just had to add the following line in my application.properties

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

Comment: Are you missing the `remoteip` in your code block? At least of today, the attributes are documented as `server.tomcat.remoteip.remote-ip-header` and `server.tomcat.remoteip.protocol-header`.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly enabling [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security):

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers()
            .hsts()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/status", "/actuator").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but spring security keep changing protocol..
https://host:443/home -> https://host:443/securedPage -> redirect ->  http://host:80/login